# CURL server data transfer timeout

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am using the following code to get the xml data form icecat.biz:

```
set_time_limit (0);
$login = "Arpan";
$password = "arpan";
//$url="http://data.icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/EN/files.index.xml";
$url= "http://data.icecat.biz/export/level4/EN";
//$url="http://data.icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/DE/10.xml";

$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;
Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.8.0.9) Gecko/20061206 Firefox/1.5.0.9';
        $header = array(
        "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,
text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
        "Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
        "Keep-Alive: 300");
$local_path = "myxml.xml";
$file_handle = fopen($local_path, "w");

ob_start();
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_handle); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 //curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login . ":" . $password);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // times out after 4s
 //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 //$head = curl_exec($ch);

 $result = curl_exec ($ch);

 if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

 curl_close($ch);
 ob_end_clean();
 fclose ($file_handle);



$xmlStr = file_get_contents($local_path);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);



print "<pre>";
//print_r($xmlObj->Product->ProductRelated->attributes()->ID);
print_r($xmlObj);
exit;
```

The page is being executed for a unlimited  time but the XML is not being updated after 10 to 20 sec. The output xml is also not being completed. I think after a certain time the server is not responding or data is not being transferred.

Here is the error message:

```
**** The server xml (icecat) size is big
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is it possible at all that you are running out of memory? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not giving enough time for the request to download properly.

Uncomment your //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

And put the timeout to 600 for a test.

Beyond that your request looks fine, you could always check to see if the server is caching responses, the last thing that I've seen recently happening is if some of my users have reverse proxies in order to cache their normal operations.  Where some truncated responses got cached and thats all they got back for a 24 hour period although that may not be related to you.

Comment: @gintas thats a good point.  Memory limitation could be a real possibility, we may need to also see at least some of the response to find and log file output.  Although if the response just keeps churning it may not be related to memory as php will error out stating that the memory was exhausted

Comment: Hi Will H, thanks for your response. I have used
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
I think it means "unlimited time of curl execution"  .

actually I need unlimited time execution. Because the server xml size is too big.

The issue remains......

Thanks

Comment: "@gintas thats a good point. Memory limitation could be a real possibility, we may need to also see at least some of the response to find and log file output. Although if the response just keeps churning it may not be related to memory as php will error out stating that the memory was exhausted"

Comment:
   No there is no memory related err or curl related error I am getting at the time of execution